# Python: convert a list of lists into a Dictionary using comprehension

Tags: python-3.x

I want to get the output of `lsblk` into a dictionary with dev name as key.
My current solution is:

```
cmd_line = "lsblk -rno NAME,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,UUID,LABEL,FSTYPE,TRAN"
all_drives = [list(filter(None, drive.split(" "))) for drive in list(filter(None, os.popen(cmd_line).read().splitlines()))]
drives_dict = {}
for element in all_drives:
    drives_dict[element[0]] = element[1:]
```

which works fine. I was just wondering how to convert the `for` loop into a dictionary comprehension.

EDIT: the final result looks like:

```
{"sda":['some','details','here'],"sda1":['some','other','stuff','maybe','longer'],...}
```

Comment: `drives_dict = {element[0]: element[1:] for element in all_drives}`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: right... feel a bit ashamed. stumbling on the learning curve I guess. and sorry for the late thanx: covid19 freakshow is getting the best from all of us